# Trying to run two functions when document is ready

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to run two pieces of code within the  `$(document).ready(function() {` of jquery. But the code :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'getallurls'
});
```

is not being called when I add :

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
});
```

To :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').dataTable().makeEditable({
        sDeleteURL: "/deleteRow"
    });

    $('#example').dataTable( {
         "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
    });
```

Here is the complete code snippet :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').dataTable().makeEditable({
        sDeleteURL: "/deleteRow"
    });

    $('#example').dataTable({
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
    }); 

    $.ajax({
        url: 'getallurls', ...............   
    });
});
```

Comment: Chances are pretty good that you have a javascript error which is halting execution.  Did you check the error console or debug console for errors?

Comment: I did, it was throwing an error. thanks, it couln't find a javascript file.

Comment: Next time you see an error that you can't figure out, tell us EXACTLY what the error says so perhaps we can help.

Comment: I should have checked error console first, thanks for comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making two calls to `.dataTable()`, which it won't like.  Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').dataTable({
        sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
    }).makeEditable({
        sDeleteURL: "/deleteRow"
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'getallurls'   
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/cfJys/